# What is the use of 'software' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's already a [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) tag, which has a tag wiki entry. The [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag has no tag wiki entry, but seems to be used synonymously with software-industry, or used incorrectly.

Is this tag still necessary, and if so, how is it to be used?

Comment: these should probably be [meta-tag:tag-synonyms]. I would also suggest to synonymize [tag:software-development] because even if we delete it (which would _in theory_ be right thing to do), there will be a high risk of it being resurrected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the intent was that [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) is for questions about *software itself*, like [Justifying the installation of utility applications on company laptop](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19199/justifying-the-installation-of-utility-applications-on-company-laptop).  [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry), on the other hand, is about an industry.  It looks like the former has not always been correctly applied -- not having a tag wiki probably contributes to that.

Comment: so, what would be a solution? unambiguous tag wiki to "software" plus retagging all questions that went there by mistake? and what about "software-development"?

Comment: @gnat yeah, I think someone needs to go through the [tag:software] questions, retag any that are really [tag:software-industry], and then look at what's left and write a tag wiki (or at least an excerpt).  Maybe that tag should really be called something like "software-use" to make it more clear it's not about software dev?  (I haven't reviewed the questions beyond a quick skim.)

Comment: "software-use" sounds like much more accurate tag name! Actually, I'd make "software" a synonym of software-use, to prevent it from being mistakenly recreated again (I'm sure it will resurrect if we simply remove it)

Comment: If we have both software-use and software-industry, I don't want software to be a synonym of either.  When you start typing that word you should be presented with both completions.

Comment: I think you'd be presented with both anyway - tag completion simply pulls out all tags that start with letters you type, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

as gnat said:
these should probably be tag-synonyms. I would also suggest to synonymize software-development because even if we delete it (which would in theory be right thing to do), there will be a high risk of it being resurrected

Comment: A synonym that's a strict substring of another tag isn't all that helpful; if "software" isn't there and people start typing that, the system will suggest "software-industry".  Synonyms are really intended for cases where the words to describe an idea are more different.