# Can we remove the legal tag?

Tags: discussion, legal-questions, burninate-request

It seems that despite the [decision](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/whats-the-legal-tag-for) to ban the legal tag six years ago, it's still alive and well.  The majority of questions that use this tag seem to get closed almost immediately and its continued existence seems to suggest to newcomers that it's okay to ask "is it legal" questions.

Comment: No need to accept my answer right away; just because I'm a moderator doesn't mean I have the final say or anything.  Maybe we can use this question to *adjust* rather than *delete* the tag, as proposed in another answer.

Comment: I believe [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/if-we-avoid-legal-advice-why-do-we-have-a-law-tag?noredirect=1&lq=10) was the most recent discussion on the tag.

Comment: And I see from that question that we also have a [tag:law] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it *was* removed back then.  It came back [a bit under three years ago](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/legal/info) and now has the following wiki excerpt:

> Questions involving local labour laws or about working within the legal system such as for the courts or lawyers. Please note that we can not provide case-specific legal advise. Also consider if your question might be more appropriate on https://law.stackexchange.com

The focus of the older meta discussion was on *legal advice*, which is off-topic here.  The current description isn't about that.  I don't know the history here (in particular, if there was another meta thread), but I don't think we should delete the *current* tag based on the *old* discussion.  (I'm not saying we shouldn't delete it *after having a new discussion based on the current definition*; I don't yet have an opinion on that.)

Comment: I agree with this. The tag now clearly refers to work-related questions on legal workplaces (courts, etc.). This could be easily answered by, say, any user with working experience on such places. I think however, that it has been **misused** by recent questions, where they include it using the "old" concept of the tag.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I suspect you're right about it being misused.  Anybody, feel free to clean up mis-applied tags or bring larger "what should we do with this class of questions" questions to meta.  Just the other day in chat I was saying that some of our tags seem a bit of a mess and it'd be nice to do something about that, but I haven't put together anything concrete yet.  Fortunately, anybody can help. :-)

Comment: Turned that comment into an answer and possible suggestion ;)

Comment: [Don't we have some legal questions that are on topic though?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice?noredirect=1&lq=1) (at least based on the top-voted answer)

Comment: Was just going to share @Dukeling's link - our current scope (as I understand it) is that legal advice is acceptable if it is something that any HR professional should know the answer to.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Monica's answer, we should not necessarily remove it.

The tag now clearly refers to work-related questions on legal workplaces (courts, etc.). This could be easily answered by, say, any user with working experience on such places.

I think however, that it has been **misused** by recent questions, where they include it using the "old" concept of the tag instead.

What I think we can do is to **rename it** to something like [legal-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-industry) instead. This would help remove the possible confusion here, as it will now be clearer that it does *not* refer to legal questions, but rather questions about legal work environment (courts, law firms, etc.).

This way would also be aligned with current ""tag standards" given the other `x-industry` tags we have in the site (like our top 3 tag [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry)).

Comment: I like the idea of renaming it.  I fear that renaming it to legal-industry will lead to questions about jobs as lawyers (like software-industry attracts questions about programmer jobs), which isn't what we want either.  Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: Well, people come here asking for programmer jobs and not necessarily do it just for the tag (or even include it). Maybe the "-industry" is not the perfect candidate, but it could work right. Other options I can think are "legal-job", "legal-company", "legal-workplace"... let's see what other think.

Comment: For [the 51 open questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=%5blegal%5d%20closed%3ano) with the [tag:legal] tag, only 2 of them appears to not be asking for legal advice, and those questions are, respectively, writing resumes when there were legal issues with the work and company interaction for appearing in court. So a [tag:legal-industry] tag wouldn't do us much good at this stage.

Comment: @Dukeling what do you suggest then? We *could* create this new tag and burninate the old legal one...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm not sure the off-topicness of **all** legal questions has been conclusively decided, so I'm not really suggesting we do anything with [tag:legal] (yet) (notwithstanding my own desire to watch all tags burn). I'm just saying creating a tag with 0 questions doesn't make sense, and is also not possible AFAIK (if there are a handful of applicable question that are specific to the legal industry, I'd be more than happy to agree that a tag would be a good idea).

Comment: When you ask a question you can create new tags if you have some small rep lvl, and if your question needs so @Dukeling

Comment: @Dukeling I think a lot of questions that could use a legal tag don't actually get one: either because no one thought of it or because the tag is sometimes removed since it's such a loaded one. Questions on overtime, reporting hours and whatnot which have been considered on-topic legal questions don't seem to get the tag. The tag is abused but imo necessary.

Answer (score -2):

How about creating *two* tags: [laws](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) and [legal-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-industry)? It doesn't sound appropriate to bundle those together into a single tag, since laws apply to all workplaces, not just those in the legal industry.

[laws](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) can be used for questions concerning laws applicable to the workplace, and ones which the legal department of a company (or even HR in some cases) can reasonably be expected to answer (example: "What is the minimum daily wage according to the Elbonian law?")

[legal-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-industry) can be used for questions about a workplace pertaining to the legal industry, such as courts and law firms.

Analogously, it isn't appropriate to subsume [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) into [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry). For example, a mom-and-pop pizza shop may be using a software to generate invoices, track inventory, etc.. A question pertaining to the software use (example: "How do we manage a software upgrade without shutting down our business for a month? :)") cannot put a pizza shop into the software industry. See also Monica's answer to my question here:  [What is the use of 'software' tag?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3222/3192)