# Tag cleanup for [software] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

After seeing someone incorrectly add the tag [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) to a question, I stumbled upon [this Meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/what-is-the-use-of-software-tag) explaining how it should be used, which is for questions about *using* software, not developing it. I fixed the tag wiki excerpt, but there are currently 116 questions with the [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag. Just glancing at the first page, it's clear that the majority of the questions are about [software-development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) or [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry), and many have those tags too, but there are also some questions that appear to be using the tag correctly.

What is the best way to go through these questions and clean up the tags so that they are better in line with the tag definitions? Or with that many questions, is it just not worth it?

Comment: I've started going through the posts. Updated my answer to include a tip I found

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to go through these questions and clean up the tags so that they are better in line with the tag definitions? Or with that many questions, is it just not worth it?

The best (and only way?) I know is to manually go over them, see if the [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)tag applies and remove it in those cases where it does not (along with starting to remove the new misuses more actively).

Maybe there are ~100 posts that require this analysis, something that surely takes time, but if it's going to make TWP better organized and clean then I say it's worth it... <sub>(I once did some "heavy" editing to some of our [meta tags](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5558/73791) and posts, they were about 30 posts involved, and it didn't take *that* long).</sub>

When I get some time I will try to go over those posts and edit the ones I see need it; if other users join the cause I am sure this will be cleaned swiftly.

---

**Update:** I have started to go through some of the posts, and I have noticed that most of the ones that I see that have the [software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag along with [software-development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) or [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) tend to have a higher chance of misusing the tag... perhaps knowing this in advance can help speed up the process.